# Duplicated iframe-request-id in url when login to a Azure hosted app which have AAD authentication using Cypress

Tags: azure, iframe, azure-active-directory, automated-tests, cypress

When I try to login to a Azure hosted app using Cypress I get below in the url. Does this mean that backend code have a redirection loop. Please help if anyone have any idea about this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The iframe-request-id is not something that is added by Cypress, this is behavior that is being done my microsoft when run through Cypress. Likely it is not expecting to be run within an iframe in the manner that Cypress runs it.

I would suggest looking into other ways to test the login through your application as explained in this doc: https://on.cypress.io/best-practices#Visiting-external-sites.

For more information you can refer this [github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7619) discussion